# How to avoid fragmented database storage by very often updates?

Tags: postgresql

When I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  "id" integer NOT NULL,
  "myval" text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "test-id-pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
```

When doing a lot of queries like the following:

```
UPDATE "test" set "myval" = "myval" || 'foobar' where "id" = 12345
```

Then the row myval will get larger and larger over time.
What will postgresql do? Where will it get the space from?

**Can I avoid that postgresql needs more than one seek to read a particular myval-column?**

Will postgresql do this automatically?

I know that normally I should try to normalize the data much more. But I need to read the value with one seek. Myval will enlarge by about 20 bytes with each update (that adds data). Some colums will have 1-2 updates, some 1000 updates.
Normally I would just use one new row instead of an update. But then selecting is getting slow.
So I came to the idea of denormalizing.

Comment: I don't get the question completely but with proper indexes, speed shouldn't be a problem. Additionally, appending values to the existing column-values all the time is way more complicated than adding new rows since you end up with less rows but these will be larger and therefore, slower. Furthermore, the query isn't quoted properly (just an FYI to save some errors).

Comment: Exactly that is the question. How much more complicated is it for the database to store these values with an update? Will postgresql read the old data and copy it to a new place? How is this managed from postgresql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the FILLFACTOR of the table to create space for future updates. This can also be HOT updates because the text field doesn't have an index, to make the update faster and autovacuum overhead lower because HOT updates use a microvacuum. The CREATE TABLE statement has some information about the [FILLFACTOR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

```
ALTER TABLE test SET (fillfactor = 70);
-- do a table rebuild to blow some space in your current table:
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE test;
-- start testing
```

The value 70 is not the perfect setting, it depends on your unique situation. Maybe you're fine with 90, it could also be 40 or something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to this question about [TEXT in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5268523/479863), or at least the answer is similar. PostgreSQL [stores large columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) away from the main table storage:

> Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values.

So you can expect a `TEXT` (or `BYTEA` or large `VARCHAR`) column to always be stored away from the main table and something like `SELECT id, myval FROM test WHERE id = 12345` will take two seeks to pull both columns off the disk (and more seeks to resolve their locations).

If your UPDATEs really are causing your SELECTs to slow down then perhaps you need to review your [vacuuming](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) strategy.

Comment: When storing the values in background tables, what will happen there when I update this value. Will it be read and then stored again, or just added?

Comment: @Chris: Presumably it would have to make a copy and change that, otherwise it wouldn't be able to properly isolate the change for whatever transactions are in effect; I don't think PostgreSQL has any fancy revision control system for this situation but I am not certain. Then the usual vacuuming process would clean up the old out of date copies.